# The boundary string in HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android

Why we have to setup a boundary string?
What is the purpose for?
any rules on it?

Comment: its better to tag this in java also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boundary String, as the name says it is boundary for different parameters in a Httprequest, But I think in java no need to use boundary.
[HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), [HttpCore](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-dev/index.html) by Apache like a lot are there for file handling Httpworks, which will be more easier and efficient